# Convert varchar "18-MAR-13" to Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion, varchar

`Varchar` value `"18-MAR-13"` needs to be **smartly** converted to date as `"18-03-2013"` in `DD-MM-YYYY` format.

None of `CAST, TRY_CAST, CONVERT, TRY_CONVERT` worked.

I have tried with `CONCAT`, but it got too long.

Comment: Is that DD-MMM-YY, or YY-MMM-DD? Which century?

Comment: there is no smat way, converting all rows costs time and resources better spent elsewhere

Comment: Hi @BTurkeli, try to explictly string replace '-' to ' ' and then it is of the exact style #6 (dd mon yy), then do a explict convert to see whether it still throws exception. here is the query "select convert(date, replace('18-MAR-13','-',' '),6)",  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7a53a4/1    MS SQL all supported styles are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187928(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with the appropriate style - assuming 13 means 2013, if not clarify in the question.

```
select Convert(varchar(10),Convert(date, '18-MAR-13'), 105)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the column gives `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` error. There are null values in the column.

Comment: then chack for NULL and add inszead a value

Comment: @BTurkeli Then you have _bad data_ which is a direct result of storing a date as a string _in the first place_. Find it using `TRY_PARSE`: [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/C30SlCDh). If you're storing a date it should be stored as a date, period. That error is not caused by NULLs, it's caused by garbage.

Comment: I know, but thanks.

Comment: @BTurkeli Not sure I follow - what do you know? Everything we've told you? So how can we help? What do you want SQL Server to do when you say "convert this column to a date" but it hits a row with garbage in that column? Do you want to ignore the row, make the value NULL, raise an error, ...?

Comment: TRY_PARSE works better.